Test of difference of Coefficients of a same regression
Sir
I have run a regression, where I estimated effect of two independent variables A and B on an outcome variable C. How can I compare the regression coefficients of A and B to estimate whether the effect of A is greater or stronger on the outcome variable or whether B has a stronger impact on C, and whether both coefficients obtained are significantly different from each other so that I can assume that both independent variables have differing impacts on the outcome variable? or whose has a greater effect on C?
Can you Help in this regard?

A good discussion of variable importance in regression models can be found here: Grömping, U. (2015). Variable importance in regression models. WIREs Comput Stat7, 137-152. DOI: 10.1002/wics.1346
